# Scroll not working in vertical list created using ListView?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've created a vertical list inside a scrollable container. But the issue I'm facing is that the list is not scrolling.

This is the component which creates the parent container.

```
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
  String _date = "Today";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.checkLoginStatus();
  }

  checkLoginStatus() async {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (sharedPreferences.getString("token") == null) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => Login(),
        ),
        (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: loggedInBar(sharedPreferences, context),
      drawer: appDrawer(sharedPreferences, context),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: hexToColor("#FFFFFF"),
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              hero(),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 20, 30, 0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    customText(
                      '$_date',
                      "#000000",
                      "26.0",
                      TextAlign.center,
                      "Roboto Black",
                      FontWeight.w900,
                    ),
                    OutlineButton(
                      child: Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        height: 42.0,
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      customText(
                                        "CHOOSE DAY",
                                        "#EC2F3C",
                                        "18",
                                        TextAlign.center,
                                        "Roboto Bold",
                                        FontWeight.w800,
                                      ),
                                      Icon(
                                        Icons.date_range,
                                        size: 22.0,
                                        color: hexToColor("#EC2F3C"),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        DatePicker.showDatePicker(context,
                            theme: DatePickerTheme(
                              containerHeight: 210.0,
                            ),
                            showTitleActions: true,
                            minTime: DateTime(
                              DateTime.now().year - 100,
                              DateTime.now().month,
                              DateTime.now().day,
                            ),
                            maxTime: DateTime(
                              DateTime.now().year - 17,
                              DateTime.now().month,
                              DateTime.now().day,
                            ), onConfirm: (date) {
                          print('confirm $date');
                          var dateString = date;
                          var formattedDate = Jiffy(dateString).yMMMd;
                          setState(() {
                            _date = formattedDate;
                          });
                        }, currentTime: DateTime.now(), locale: LocaleType.en);
                      },
                      color: hexToColor("#efefef"),
                      splashColor: hexToColor("#efefef"),
                      highlightElevation: 2,
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: hexToColor("#EC2F3C"),
                        width: 2,
                      ),
                      highlightedBorderColor: hexToColor("#EC2F3C"),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              AllEvents(), // the widget which creates the list(mentioned below)
              SizedBox(height: 30),
              footer(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The widget which creates the list is this.

```
class _AllEventsState extends State<AllEvents> {
  final String url = "<api url>";
  List data;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getAllEvents();
  }

  createRoute(id) {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/eventdetail', arguments: id);
  }

  Future<String> getAllEvents() async {
    var response = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull(url),
      headers: {"Accept": "application/json"},
    );

    setState(() {
      var convertDataToJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
      data = convertDataToJson["events"];
    });
    return "Success";
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ScrollController _controller = new ScrollController();
    return Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        controller: _controller,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext cont, int index) {
          // format date
          var dateString = data[index]["eventDate"];
          var eventDate = Jiffy(dateString).MMMEd;
          if (data == null) {
            return Center(
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 20, 30, 20),
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 7, 30, 7),
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        createRoute(data[index]['_id']);
                      },
                      child: Card(
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(
                              width: 3,
                              color: hexToColor("#EBEBEB"),
                            ),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                          ),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 20),
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  customText(
                                    eventDate.toString(),
                                    "#000000",
                                    "20.0",
                                    TextAlign.left,
                                    "Roboto Black",
                                    FontWeight.w900,
                                  ),
                                  customText(
                                    "10, 9",
                                    "#000000",
                                    "20.0",
                                    TextAlign.right,
                                    "Roboto Black",
                                    FontWeight.w900,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 20),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: customText(
                                      "${data[index]['city']} | ${data[index]['arenaName']} | ${data[index]['categories'][0]['title']}",
                                      "#000000",
                                      "18.0",
                                      TextAlign.left,
                                      "Roboto Black",
                                      FontWeight.w900,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The scroll is only working on touching outside the list area and once the list area covers the entire screen I'm unable to scroll the page further. I think I'm doing many mistakes here as I'm a noob in flutter. I'm unable to wrap my head around what I'm doing wrong as I don't think this is how it's supposed to work.

Please help me fix this issue. Any help would be great? Thank you

Comment: `physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),`

Comment: wow, it worked, thanks a lot. I'm such a noob though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the scroll physics of list to `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics`

```
ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        controller: _controller,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext cont, int index) {
// code for building list item
});
```